# SSRS - Get value from different row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a row group that returns monthly totals. For example I have column January, February. There are 3 rows.

```
Description January   February
Total         1000      0
Spending       10       0
Percentage     10%     [Blank]
```

In the column february, when the Total is zero, the percentage should be set to nothing/blank. I have tried to use the expression below:

```
=IIf((Fields!Description.Value = "Percentage" AND 
Previous(Fields!February.Value)=0),nothing,Sum(Fields!February.Value))
```

But I get an error - The value expression for the text box 'textbox51' has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function...

My question is, how do we check if the value in the cell 2 rows before is 0 and sent the value in the 
current cell (percentage) to nothing?

Comment: Are you using a "Matrix" object or "Table" object? , if you using a "Table" object, are your results are grouping on the data sets or by the group tablix?

Comment: Hi, I am using Table object and the results grouping are by data sets.

Comment: you can try to achieve this by implementing the "expression" in the query on the "data set" by "CASE" or "IF" and not in the expression on the "text box" field.